# How to create an array of objects from json response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I get this error:

> undefined method `name' for ["id", "6309"]:Array

I want show league name for each response inplay events

Json Response:

```
{
    "success": 1,
    "pager": {
        "page": 1,
        "per_page": 50,
        "total": 21
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "222434",
            "time": "1489669200",
            "time_status": "1",
            "league": {
                "id": "4148",
                "name": "Viareggio Cup",
                "cc": null
            },
            "home": {
                "id": "43717",
                "name": "Fiorentina U19",
                "image_id": "42466",
                "cc": "it"
            },
            "away": {
                "id": "159690",
                "name": "Garden City Panthers FC U19",
                "image_id": "320141",
                "cc": null
            },
            "timer": {
                "tm": 86,
                "ts": 4,
                "tt": "1"
            },
            "scores": {
                "2": {
                    "home": "2",
                    "away": "0"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "id": "223265",
            "time": "1489669200",
            "time_status": "1",
            "league": {
                "id": "1501",
                "name": "Uganda Division 2",
                "cc": "ug"
            },
            "home": {
                "id": "159745",
                "name": "Simba FC",
                "image_id": null,
                "cc": null
            },
            "away": {
                "id": "80323",
                "name": "Busia Fisheries",
                "image_id": null,
                "cc": null
            },
            "timer": {
                "tm": 69,
                "ts": 1,
                "tt": "1"
            },
            "scores": {
                "2": {
                    "home": "1",
                    "away": "2"
                }
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

---

```
module Bapi
  class Inplay < Base
    attr_accessor :id,
                  :time,
                  :time_status,
                  :league

    CACHE_DEFAULTS = { expires_in: 7.days, force: false }

    def self.all(query = {})
      response = Request.where("/v2/events/inplay",query, CACHE_DEFAULTS)
      events = response.fetch('results', []).map { |inplay| Inplay.new(inplay) }
      [ events, response[:errors] ]
    end

    def initialize(args = {})
      super(args)
      league = parse_leagues(args)
    end


     private

    def parse_leagues(args = {})
      args.fetch("league", []).map { |league| League.new(league) }
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
 module Bap
     class Base
        attr_accessor :errors

        def initialize(args = {})
          args.each do |name, value|
            attr_name = name.to_s
            send("#{attr_name}=", value) if respond_to?("#{attr_name}=")
          end
        end
      end
    end
```

---

League model

```
module Bapi
  class League < Base
    attr_accessor :id,
                  :name,
                  :cc
  end
end
```

---

Controller :

```
@events, @errors = Bapi::Inplay.all
```

---

views :

```
<% @events.each_slice(3) do |events| %>
    <% events.each do |event| %>
     <% event.league.each do |leg| %>
            <%= leg.name %>      
     <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

---

```
[#<Bap::Inplay:0x00007feceede0570 @id="873482", @time="1534143600", @time_status="1", @league={"id"=>"6309", "name"=>"China Super League Reserves", "cc"=>"cn"}>, #<Bap::Inplay:0x00007feceedeb6f0 @id="875996", @time="1534147192", @time_status="1", @league={"id"=>"3653", "name"=>"Indonesia Cup", "cc"=>"id"}>]
```

When i changed code like this it's work fine

---

```
   <% @events.each_slice(3) do |events| %>
        <% events.each do |event| %>
         <%= event.time %>
         <%= event.time_status %>         
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
     <% end %>
```

---

Edited : 
I found this 
 
Now how i can define a variable to convert arguments to (key value), when i use key its return value

```
    <% @events.each_slice(3) do |events| %>
        <% events.each do |event| %>
     <% event.league.each do |k,v| %>
            <%= k %> <br>
            <%= v %>         
       <% end %>      
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: It might help if you could produce a smaller code example to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the problem is in this method:

```
def initialize(args = {})
  super(args)
  league = parse_leagues(args)
end
```

The leagues are parsed and set to a local variable, but is expected to be set to an instance one:

```
def initialize(args = {})
  super(args)
  @league = parse_leagues(args)
end
```

Otherwise, the default implementation from `Base` is called and `@league` is set to a raw value (to a hash)

And also `parse_leagues` method should be fixed (and probably renamed to `parse_league`, since the raw value is not an array, but a hash):

```
def parse_leagues(args = {})
  League.new(args.fetch("league", {}))
end
```

And then use it in the view as following:

```
<% @events.each_slice(3) do |events| %>
  <% events.each do |event| %>
    <%= event.league.name %>    
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Its response false

Comment: @Gasem could you elaborate?

Comment: When i use `@league` in initialize its return nothing and without any error in views , When i use  `<%= event.league.present? %>` its return `false`

Comment: @Gasem updated my answer, haven't noticed, that raw value of "league" is a hash, not an array

Comment: thanks its helpful , but still not work  , when use @league  return this error  `undefined method 'each' for #<Bapi::League:> `

Comment: @Gasem that's because you don't need each there, it's not an array, updated my answer

Comment: its true , now how i can use events league in rails views